# Use .htm file (containing XML) as a template then resave preserving original format

Tags: php

I currently have a Snom XML file (stored as filename.htm) which I need to use as a template file to produce specific individual files.

I have attempted to load the .htm using [get_file_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) however I either lose the tags in the document or the formatting.

Is there a way to load contents of a file, replace template placeholders then save the new file preserving the format and original spacing?

**Template File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<settings>
    <phone-settings e="2">
        <user_active idx="1" perm="R">on</user_active>
        <user_realname idx="1" perm="R">{Prefix}{Suffix}</user_realname>
        <user_pname idx="1" perm="R">{Prefix}{Suffix}</user_pname>
        <user_name idx="1" perm="R">{Prefix}{Suffix}</user_name>
        <phone_name idx="1" perm="R">{Prefix}{Suffix}</phone_name>
        <user_idle_text idx="1" perm="R">{Prefix}{Suffix}</user_idle_text>

        <idle_offhook idx="1" perm="R">on</idle_offhook>
        <offhook_dial_prompt idx="1" perm="R">off</offhook_dial_prompt>
    </phone-settings>
</settings>
```

**Required End Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<settings>
    <phone-settings e="2">
        <user_active idx="1" perm="R">on</user_active>
        <user_realname idx="1" perm="R">Phone 001</user_realname>
        <user_pname idx="1" perm="R">Phone 001</user_pname>
        <user_name idx="1" perm="R">Phone 001</user_name>
        <phone_name idx="1" perm="R">Phone 001</phone_name>
        <user_idle_text idx="1" perm="R">Phone 001</user_idle_text>

        <idle_offhook idx="1" perm="R">on</idle_offhook>
        <offhook_dial_prompt idx="1" perm="R">off</offhook_dial_prompt>
    </phone-settings>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assming the placeholders are unique and not used elsewhere in "non-placeholder" contexts, then a simple string operation would do the trick:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('template.xml');
$xml = str_replace('{Prefix}', 'Phone', $xml);
$xml = str_replace('{Suffix}', '001', $xml);
etc...

file_put_contents('parsed.xml, $xml);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc I did try that (it's the usual way I process template files), however I lost the spacing when using file_put_contents. Should file_put_contents keep the original spacing?

Comment: file_put_contents just dumps out what you provide. if the formatting's gone, then something's removing it elsewhere.